# Multiple left join compiled in linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

In my API project, with EntityFramework, I have to translate the following SQL statement

```
 select p.cod_paquete, p.nombre, a.descripcion, a.proceso, a.color, a.descripcion, (select count(*) from paqueteAcabado where paquete=a.paquete and color=a.color), coalesce(pc.titulo,''), case when pc.opcional=1 then 1 else 0 end as opcional, pa.optativo, a.opcional 
  from paqueteAPP pa 
  inner join paquete p on p.cod_paquete=pa.paquete 
  left join paqueteAcabado a on a.paquete=p.cod_paquete and a.opcional=1 
  left join coste c on c.cod_coste=a.acabado 
  left join paqueteColor pc on pc.paquete=p.cod_paquete and pc.color=a.color 
  where pa.agrupacionProductoProducto= '298'
  order by coalesce(pa.orden,0), p.cod_paquete, a.color, a.descripcion
```

**The class**

```
public class SQLResultadoPaquetesAcabado
    {
        public short cod_paquete { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public short proceso { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public int? paquetesColor { get; set; }
        public string titulo { get; set; }
        public bool? PaqueteColoropcional { get; set; }
        public bool optativo { get; set; }
        public bool? acabadoOpcional { get; set; }

    }
```

**The sql translated in Linq**

```
 int codigo = 298;
 Paquetes = (from paqueteAPP pa in db.paqueteAPP
                    join paquete p in db.paquete on pa.paquete equals p.cod_paquete
                    join paqueteAcabado a in db.paqueteAcabado on p.cod_paquete equals a.paquete into pcacabado
                    from pacabado in pcacabado.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join coste c in db.coste on pacabado.acabado equals c.cod_coste into pacabadocoste1
                    from pcosteacabado in pacabadocoste1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join paqueteColor pc in db.paqueteColor on p.cod_paquete equals pc.paquete into pcolor
                    from pacolor in pcolor.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where pa.agrupacionProductoProducto == codigo && pacabado.opcional == true
                    select new SQLResultadoPaquetesAcabado
                    {
                        cod_paquete = p.cod_paquete,
                        nombre = p.nombre,
                        descripcion = pacabado.descripcion,
                        proceso = pacabado.proceso,
                        color = pacabado.color,
                        paquetesColor = (from paqueteAcabado pa in db.paqueteAcabado
                                         where pa.paquete == pacabado.paquete && pa.color == 
 pacabado.color
                                         select pa).Count(),

                        titulo = pacolor.titulo,
                        PaqueteColoropcional = pacolor.opcional,
                        optativo = pa.optativo,
                        acabadoOpcional = pacabado.opcional
                    });
```

**The SQL that is obtained when translating from Linq to SQL**

```
SELECT COUNT
[Project1].[agrupacionProductoProducto] AS [agrupacionProductoProducto], 
[Project1].[cod_paquete] AS [cod_paquete], 
[Project1].[nombre] AS [nombre], 
[Project1].[descripcion] AS [descripcion], 
[Project1].[proceso] AS [proceso], 
[Project1].[color] AS [color], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[titulo] AS [titulo], 
[Project1].[opcional1] AS [opcional], 
[Project1].[optativo] AS [optativo], 
[Project1].[opcional] AS [opcional1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[agrupacionProductoProducto] AS [agrupacionProductoProducto], 
    [Filter1].[optativo] AS [optativo], 
    [Filter1].[cod_paquete] AS [cod_paquete], 
    [Filter1].[nombre] AS [nombre], 
    [Filter1].[proceso] AS [proceso], 
    [Filter1].[descripcion] AS [descripcion], 
    [Filter1].[opcional] AS [opcional], 
    [Filter1].[color] AS [color], 
    [Extent4].[titulo] AS [titulo], 
    [Extent4].[opcional] AS [opcional1], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[paqueteAcabado] AS [Extent5]
        WHERE ([Extent5].[paquete] = [Filter1].[paquete1]) AND (([Extent5].[color] = [Filter1].[color]) OR (([Extent5].[color] IS NULL) AND ([Filter1].[color] IS NULL)))) AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[agrupacionProductoProducto] AS [agrupacionProductoProducto], [Extent1].[optativo] AS [optativo], [Extent2].[cod_paquete] AS [cod_paquete], [Extent2].[nombre] AS [nombre], [Extent3].[proceso] AS [proceso], [Extent3].[paquete] AS [paquete1], [Extent3].[descripcion] AS [descripcion], [Extent3].[opcional] AS [opcional], [Extent3].[color] AS [color]
        FROM   [dbo].[paqueteAPP] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[paquete] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[paquete] = [Extent2].[cod_paquete]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[paqueteAcabado] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[cod_paquete] = [Extent3].[paquete]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent3].[opcional] ) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[paqueteColor] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[cod_paquete] = [Extent4].[paquete]
    WHERE [Filter1].[agrupacionProductoProducto] = '298'
)  AS [Project1]
```

**My problem is that the SQL consists of three left join**

**And with linq I can only generate a single left join as you can see in the result of the generation of linq to sql**

*SQL*

```
left join paqueteAcabado a on a.paquete=p.cod_paquete and a.opcional=1 
left join coste c on c.cod_coste=a.acabado 
left join paqueteColor pc on pc.paquete=p.cod_paquete and pc.color=a.color
```

*Linq*

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[paquete] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[paquete] = [Extent2].[cod_paquete]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[paqueteAcabado] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[cod_paquete] = [Extent3].[paquete]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent3].[opcional] ) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[paqueteColor] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[cod_paquete] = [Extent4].[paquete]
```

My question is, how do I successfully reproduce the SQL through linq without using a distinct? Because with a distinct, I get the result I want, but I get 120 repeated rows, which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

I work my own code but code converting is very hard. However, I try to explain to create left outer joins like sql queries.

Keep in mind that, that's not final query. You have to add inner queries (I think you could) and if you get join keywords not match exception you should add same names.

Now code is here, I try to convert some parts:

```
var joinTest = context.paqueteAPP.Join(context.paquete,
        pa => pa.paquete,
        p => p.cod_paquete,
        (pa, p) =>
            new {p.cod_paquete, p.nombre,p.cod_paquete})
    .GroupJoin(context.paqueteAcabado,
        a => new
        {
            a.paquete,
            a.opcional
        }, 
        temp => new {paquete=temp.cod_paquete,opcional=1},
        (temp, paqueteAcabado) => new {temp.cod_paquete, temp.nombre, paqueteAcabado})
    .SelectMany(s => s.paqueteAcabado.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (s, paqueteAcabado) => new {s.cod_paquete, s.nombre,paqueteAcabado.descripcion, paqueteAcabado.proceso, paqueteAcabado.color, paqueteAcabado.descripcion,paqueteAcabado.acabado})
    .GroupJoin(context.coste,
        a => a.acabado, c => c.cod_coste,
        (temp, coste) => new { temp.cod_paquete, temp.nombre,temp.descripcion, temp.proceso, temp.color, temp.descripcion, coste })
    .SelectMany(s => s.coste.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (s, coste) => new { s.cod_paquete, s.nombre,s.descripcion, s.proceso, s.color, s.descripcion, coste.Name })
    .ToList();
```

This query create 1 inner and 2 left joins.

If you need more help, please add entities (what you need) and some data.